# Get SSID from another wireless router

Tags: wifi

I have a friend who has two routers in his house and lost (forgot) the SSID name of one of two routers. Anyone knows how I (he) can get the SSID name from the lost router?

Comment: I guess you meant SSID and I don't think this is sysadmin related

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just reset it to the defaults and it should go back to whatever the manufacture sets it to. linksys ssid is linksys. You could use a tool like kismet to passively sniff the ssid.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you didn't keep a note of it when you configured the router and that you are entitled to access the router and change its configuration ...

1. Is the SSID configured on PC(s) that access(ed) the router?
2. Log in to the router over wired Ethernet using telnet (or HTTP if supported) and look at the configuration.
3. If the router is broadcasting its SSID then it should be visible as an available wireless network with a high signal strength.
4. Reset the router configuration (the manual will advise on how this is done) and re-configure it.
5. It may be possible to sniff the router -- but if it is not broadcasting its SSID and no devices are connecting to it (see 1) you may have a long wait.